# Docker / Net 5 / Linux container exception: Unable to load shared library 'kernel32' or one of its dependencies

Tags: docker

I have a C# .Net5 console application which works fine on Windows 10 Pro.

I put the app in a Docker container to run in Linux on my Windows machine (WSL 2).

The app allocates a chunk (1 GB) of global memory (my app runs in 'unsafe' mode).

```
ptrChunk = (MemoryChunk*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(new IntPtr(ChunkSize)).ToPointer();
```

It then tries to open and read directly from the file into this unmanaged memory.

The code that fails (tries to open a verified as existing file):

```
_handle = CreateFile
(
  fileName,   //-- file name to create
  access,     //-- desired access
  sharedMode, //-- share mode
  0,          //-- security attributes
  mode,       //-- FileMode.OpenOrCreate
  0,          //-- flags and attributes: FileAttributes.Normal
  0           //-- template file
);
```

The `CreateFile` is defined as as an `extern`:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true, CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode)]
static extern unsafe System.IntPtr CreateFile
(
    string FileName,          // file name
    uint DesiredAccess,       // access mode
    uint ShareMode,           // share mode
    uint SecurityAttributes,  // Security Attributes
    uint CreationDisposition, // how to create
    uint FlagsAndAttributes,  // file attributes
    int hTemplateFile         // handle to template file
);
```

The exception:

```
Unable to load shared library 'kernel32' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libkernel32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
TraceBack      at DataAccess.OsFileIO.CreateFile(String FileName, UInt32 
DesiredAccess, UInt32 ShareMode, UInt32 SecurityAttributes, UInt32 
CreationDisposition, UInt32 FlagsAndAttributes, Int32 hTemplateFile)
  at DataAccess.OsFileIO.Open(String fileName, OpenFlags openFlags, OpenMode 
                              modeFlags) in /src/DataAccess/OsFileIO.cs:line 192
```

My Docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TseShard/TseShard.csproj", "TseShard/"]
COPY ["Utils/Utils.csproj", "Utils/"]
COPY ["BinarySerialization/BinarySerialization.csproj", "BinarySerialization/"]
COPY ["Interfaces/Interfaces.csproj", "Interfaces/"]
COPY ["JsonCompare/JsonCompare.csproj", "JsonCompare/"]
COPY ["Networking/Networking.csproj", "Networking/"]
COPY ["FilterScoring/FilterScoring.csproj", "FilterScoring/"]
COPY ["DataAccess/DataAccess.csproj", "DataAccess/"]
COPY ["TseClient/TseClient.csproj", "TseClient/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TseShard/TseShard.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TseShard"
RUN dotnet build "TseShard.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TseShard.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
#ENV LD_DEBUG=all
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TseShard.dll"]
```

The problem is 100% reproducible.

Adding the:
ENV LD_DEBUG=all

to the Docker did not help.

I need to use unmanaged memory so I can't use regular C# managed I/O.

**How should I build the container image to get around this problem?**